# React Native WebView onMessage IOS issue

Tags: react-native, webview

**Intro**

Working on this messaging between ReactNative and a WebView and the onMessage doesn't seem to be very stable on IOS.

However, on Android it works just fine.

I've tried a bunch of different packages but ended up doing it from scratch and I don't even get the simplest use case to work.

**Problem**

What works and what not?

- Android: sending & receiving works just fine
- IOS: sending to WebView works, receiving from doesn't

**Visual results**
[image] 
[image]

As can be seen on the screenshots on IOS, whenever I try to send a message from the webview's content to RN, it gives a weird error saying *"Asset not found"*.

**Code**

**App.js**

```
 ...
 handleButtonPressed = () => {
    this.webview.postMessage("Hello from RN")
  }

  onMessage = (event) => {
    alert(event.nativeEvent.data)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View
          style={styles.webView}
        >
          <WebView
            ref={r => this.webview = r}
            source={html}
            onMessage={this.onMessage}
          />
        </View>
        <Button
          onPress={this.handleButtonPressed}
          title='Press me'
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
  ...
```

**javascript of imported html (unminified)**

This code is compiled using webpack & babel but thats not causing the issue for sure.

```
const button = document.getElementById('send')

document.addEventListener('message', function(data) {
  alert(data.data)
})

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.postMessage("Sending data from WebView", "*")
})
```

**Error from expo**

```
[21:19:09] Error: invalid asset file path: `${filePath}
[21:19:09]     at Object.parse (/Users/jimvercoelen/Desktop/braintree-payment/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/lib/AssetPaths.js:66:11)
[21:19:09]     at /Users/jimvercoelen/Desktop/braintree-payment/node_modules/metro/src/Assets.js:312:34
[21:19:09]     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
[21:19:09]     at step (/Users/jimvercoelen/Desktop/braintree-payment/node_modules/metro/src/Assets.js:326:347)
[21:19:09]     at /Users/jimvercoelen/Desktop/braintree-payment/node_modules/metro/src/Assets.js:326:577
[21:19:09]     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
[21:19:09]     at /Users/jimvercoelen/Desktop/braintree-payment/node_modules/metro/src/Assets.js:326:258
[21:19:09]     at getAsset (/Users/jimvercoelen/Desktop/braintree-payment/node_modules/metro/src/Assets.js:326:58)
[21:19:09]     at /Users/jimvercoelen/Desktop/braintree-payment/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:576:1722
[21:19:09]     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

**Deps**

- "expo": "^32.0.0"
- "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",

I lost track of what I've tried and what not but right now don't know what to try anymore since I can't really find any similar problems.

Any help / input is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting the useWebKit property to true on the webview? I had this same problem and that fixed it for me. I believe this is an issue specific to version 32 of expo.

Comment: @CSharp no I didn't. Thanks for the comment tho!

Comment: Did you find any solution for same?